# ECONNREFUSED: Connection Refused localhost:11211 - Dalli / Memcachier / Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memcached, dalli

So on heroku I am getting this issue. I can't quite figure out why this is happening.

```
heroku run rails c
 > cache = Dalli::Client.new
 > Rails.cache.write('memcachier', 'rocks')
Dalli::Server#connect localhost:11211

localhost:11211 failed (count: 1) Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - send
localhost:11211 failed (count: 1) Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - send
localhost:11211 is down
localhost:11211 is down
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you either don't have the `memcachier` gem installed, or you haven't added the memcachier addon to your Heroku app.

You can install the memcachier addon from the command line:

```
heroku addons:add memcachier:dev
```

Then make sure that you have both the `dalli` gem and the `memcachier` gems in your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'dalli'
gem 'memcachier'
```

Run `bundle install`, check in your updated `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, push it all up to Heroku and try the `Rails.cache.write` again.